# Add Contact to ListView Android

Tags: android, list, listview, contacts

I'd like to add my selected PhonesContacts(currently 2 strings) to a listview.
Currently im doing this: (Name and PhoneNo are written to the textview)

How can i change this to listview?

I tried creating an ArrayList and passing the string to this ArrayList but this hasn't been working.

```
private void contactPicked(Intent data) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String phoneNo = null ;
        String name = null;
        // getData() method will have the Content Uri of the selected contact
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        //Query the content uri
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        // column index of the phone number
        int  phoneIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        // column index of the contact name
        int  nameIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        phoneNo = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
        name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
        // Set the value to the textviews
        textView1.setText(name);
        textView2.setText(phoneNo);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

For the listview i created a

```
private ListView listView;
```

and used it in my OnCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_view);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Comment: Have you added this permission in manifest:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

Comment: Yes i have it's working already but i need listview instead of textView.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following examples for listing contacts into listview.

[Display All Contacts from Contacts application in ListView](http://ramsandroid4all.blogspot.in/2014/01/display-all-contacts-from-contacts.html)

[Retrieving and Listing Contacts in ListView Example](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-contacts-content-provider-retrieving-and-listing-contacts-in-listview-example/)

[Get contact list and show in custom listview android](https://trinitytuts.com/get-contact-list-and-show-in-custom-listview-android/)

Example:

MainActivity.class

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    LinearLayout ll;
    Button loadBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        loadBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        loadBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                LoadContactsAyscn lca = new LoadContactsAyscn();
                lca.execute();
            }
        });

    }

    class LoadContactsAyscn extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
        ProgressDialog pd;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Loading Contacts",
                    "Please Wait");
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ArrayList<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>();

            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    null, null, null);
            while (c.moveToNext()) {

                String contactName = c
                        .getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String phNumber = c
                        .getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                contacts.add(contactName + ":" + phNumber);

            }
            c.close();

            return contacts;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> contacts) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(contacts);

            pd.cancel();

            ll.removeView(loadBtn);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getApplicationContext(), R.layout.text, contacts);

            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Load Contacts"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#ffccff"
        android:divider="#00ffff"
        android:dividerHeight="2sp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

text.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:textSize="25sp" >

</TextView>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ram.displayallcontacts"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.ram.displayallcontacts.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I think this will help you to solve your problem. Please let me know whether its solved.

Comment: It's not working actually.
All i would need to do is write my currently used strings name and phoneNo to the listview ... i shouldnt write the whole code new when i have something already working but only with textview

Answer (score 0):

if you want to choose one contact and add to list, you need :

- Use [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)
- [Custom Adapter](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)
- Add item (name, phoneNo) to Adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() at adapter object

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object class containing string `name` and `contact`

```
public class Data {

    private String name = "";
    private String contact = "";
    public void Data(String n, String a){

        name = n;
        contact = a;

    }

}
```

then you do

```
ArrayList<Data> Contacts = new ArrayList<Data>();
Data objt = new Data(name,phoneNo); // name, phoneNo are data from database
Contacts.add(objt); // Adding it to the list
```

Then you can set this arraylist to your listview

Comment: im not able/allowed to use strings in data arraylist dude

Comment: Ive changed my question so u might better understand

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [this](https://github.com/activesince93/ContentProvider) Git Repository:

This repository contains following things: 
 1. Get Contacts from device.
 2. Display them in ListView
 3. Delete/Update contact.